# Usercontrol button not fireing event

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a button that shows a message box when you click it. The button is made as a user control and it's put inside a panel container. What i want to do is when you click the button, the controls dissapear within the panel.

Code in usercontrol

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{

    public event EventHandler ButtonClick;

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //bubble the event up to the parent
        if (this.ButtonClick != null)
            this.ButtonClick(this, e);
        MessageBox.Show("Test"); //test if the button itself is working
    }

}
```

Code in Form

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    UserControl1 usercontrol1 = new UserControl1();

    public Form1()
    {
        usercontrol1.ButtonClick += new EventHandler(btnIsClicked);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnIsClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Controls.Clear();
    }
}
```

Having used the code above it's not working, the button works but nothing happens in the form.

Comment: use this line `usercontrol1.ButtonClick += new EventHandler(btnIsClicked);` after `InitializeComponent()`

Comment: U created user control, but dint added it anywhere.

Comment: You didn't add `usercontrol1` to `Controls` collection of the form. How did you test it?

Comment: @Saurabh srivastava I tried it, but it still doesnt work.

Comment: How do i add it to the controls of the form?

Comment: Maybe ```panel1.Controls.Add(mycontrol)``` ?

Comment: Probably the user control instance which you see on your form is different from the one which you created in above code, you didn't add that to the form. So if you see any user control on from, it's another one.

Comment: That seemed to have done the trick, thanks!